# Extend bottom navigation bar over safe area

Tags: ios, flutter, safearea

I have the following screen

[image]

and this is the code:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Palette.light,
        body: RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: () => MatchesController.refresh(matchesState, matchId),
            child: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                MatchAppBar(matchId: matchId),
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return widgets[index];
                    },
                    childCount: widgets.length,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )),
        bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(child: BottomBarMatch(match: match)),
```

the problem is that I want to use `SafeArea` and `bottomBarMatch` and `Scaffold` have different colors.

I would like that space below the bottom bar to be of the same color of the bottom bar.
If I move the `SafeArea` one layer up I would instead see it black (system color, I guess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead using `SafeArea` widget, I recommend adding the padding

```dart
MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom
```

to your `BottomBarMatch` widget

Give this padding to the white colored widget of your `BottomBarMatch` widget and you'll get the same safe area but inside the `BottomBarMatch`

Comment: padding not work, it will make whole listview above bottombar with an offset

Comment: This is incorrect, this quantity is about double what it should be

Answer (score 3):

1 . Wrap `BottomNavBar` into `SafeArea`

```
SafeArea(
        child: BottomNavBar(
```

2 . Set `BottomNavigationBar` with `elevation: 0`

3 . Wrap `BottomNavigationBar` into `Container` and then make `top shadow` :

```
   BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
              blurRadius: 1,
              offset: const Offset(0.0, -0.75),
            ),



child: BottomNavigationBar(
          elevation: 0,
```

Answer (score 1):

To deal with this issue I created a custom safe area widget as follows:

```
class ColoredSafeArea extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Color color;

  const ColoredSafeArea({Key key, @required this.child, this.color})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color ?? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This allows you to set a safe area, as well as the background colour behind the top status bar and the area 'underneath' the safe area on large screen devices.

In your case, you could wrap the entire widget tree in a ColoredSafeArea widget, setting the color to white, or any color of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
This issue is fixed with Flutter 3.10.0 now.

See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/123746